# Android Automated Test between two or more devices/users

Tags: android, testing, tdd, automated-tests, integration-testing

I'm newbie in testing so it could be a very simple question, but do somebody know how to test an app automatically between two or more devices?

I have an app with some users doing some transactions between each other. I'd like to test my app automatically with two or more users. have anybody an idea for it?

I'm using [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) but the real problem is I could not run two different test actions in two differenet devices in the same time or in a defined order. I would like to see an example for it or something, because I've just saw cases when the testers were run the same action on different devices.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [appium](http://appium.io/) to automate native Android apps (iOS too).

It's built on the top of the Selenium WebDriver API, so you should be able to drive multiple devices at once by starting multiple RemoteWebDriver clients.

You would have to start one "appium server" on each device.

On your test you would created multiple RemoteWebDrivers by pointing to these servers

```
driver1 = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.100:4723/wd/hub")...
driver2 = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.101:4723/wd/hub")...
```

Some useful links:

- [Test Automation in Java with Appium](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2013/04/mobile-test-automation-in-java-with-appium/)
- [Selenium WebDriver API](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#remotewebdriver)
- Selenium WebDriver language bindings:

  - [Java](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html)
  - [Ruby](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/index.html)
  - [Python](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/index.html)
  - .[Net](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html)